# change data in "select as" query builder laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

```
$Orders=DB::table('orders')
    ->select(
        DB::raw('sum(orders.total) as sum'), 
        DB::raw('YEAR(created_at)  as data')
    )
    ->where(function ($query) use ($date_to, $date_from) {
        $query->where('orders.pay_status', 'paid')
    })
    ->groupBy("data")
    ->get();
```

I want to see sale Statistics yearly , top code work corectly but I want use Jalali date instead of miladi, so I need change `created_at` to jalali

I think I have to use my function instead of `YEAR(created_at)` or change  `groupBy` function

If I can use `verta(created_at)->year` insted of `YEAR(created_at)`, I think  fix problem

[Used Library](https://hekmatinasser.github.io/verta/en/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to loop over your results in PHP, because your library doesn't work with Query Builder.

```
foreach ($Orders as $i => $order) {
   $newDate =  Verta::parseFormat('Y', $order->data);
  
   // add new date converted to your object - not sure about the lib, look at doc
   $Orders[$i]->dateFormated = $newDate->year;
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work because start year of milady is different by jalali so data in exist in $orders not appropriate I need change data before get It

Comment: I need change groupby actually so if I can do something like 
`
groupBy(function($val) {
        return verta($val->created_at)->year
})
`

Answer (score 0):

you cant convert the value of created_at to jalali on query , you need to calculate start & end of each jalaly year to miladi

```
1399-01-01 -> 2020-03-01
1399-12-31 -> 2021-02-01
```

you can put them in an array

```
$converted_dates = 
[
    '1397' => [
        'xxx' , 
        'xxx'
    ]
    ,'1398' => [
        'xxx' , 
        'xxxx'
    ]
    ,
    '1399' => [
        '2020-03-01' , 
        '2021-02-01'
    ]

];
```

and

```
$stats = []; 
foreach($converted_dates as $year=>$dates)
{
    $stats[$year] = DB::table('orders')
     ->select(
        DB::raw('sum(orders.total) as sum'), 
        DB::raw('YEAR(created_at)  as data')
    )
    ->whereBetween('created_at',  $dates   ))
    ->groupBy("data")
    ->get();
}
```

Comment: is not good solution because i have to update this $converted_dates  every year and if i need month this is to hard update this array every month
but if make this array auto create that is better 
but I was hoping find just query

Comment: @hh you can store stats for each month along with miladi and jalali dates in database at the end of each month so you dont have to query all the years 

but converting created_at to another value in query is not possible